# Easier way of making this SQL query nicer

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got this MySQL query here..

```
/***
 * An ugly self joining sql.
 * We want the parent's name so we have to join with the same table
 *    joining on child_row.parent_id = parent_row.id
 * Don't remove the LIMIT from this... it might be bad.
 */
$sql = 'SELECT cNode.*, pNode.name as parent_name ';
$sql.= ' FROM t_nodes AS cNode LEFT JOIN t_nodes AS pNode ';
$sql.= ' ON cNode.parent_id = pNode.id ';
$sql.='  WHERE cNode.id = '.$id.' LIMIT 1';
```

Is there any way of making this more elegant?

Comment: Your query is short and easy to understand - what do you want to improve to make it more elegant?

Comment: Personally, I don't think the table joining back to itself is at all ugly or inelegant...

Comment: This is called a [self join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Self-join). It's a often used pattern.

Comment: The only sign of evil that I can see is the comment - "Don't remove the LIMIT from this... it might be bad.". In my experience, if a query depends on LIMIT to work, it's could be working by accident, rather than by design. In this case, I'm not sure what's going on - without an order by, the row you're actually getting back is undefined; MySQL will give you back whichever row you created first, but only as a side effect. If you want the first row, I'd add "order by inserted_date" to make the intent clear.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with SQL but just to improve legibility in the PHP source:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT cNode.*, pNode.name as parent_name
    FROM t_nodes AS cNode LEFT JOIN t_nodes AS pNode
    ON cNode.parent_id = pNode.id
    WHERE cNode.id = $id LIMIT 1
";
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable alternative that I can think of is a correlated sub-query to get the parent name...

```
SELECT
  cNode.*,
  (SELECT name FROM t_nodes AS parent WHERE id = t_nodes.parent_id) AS parent_name
FROM
  t_nodes
WHERE
  cNode.id = $id
LIMIT 1
```